# Axis2 Web service client application

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

I'm trying to create Web Service application with Axis2 in Eclipse. When I generate Web Service for my class I make wizard to generate client application for my Web Service. There is  `"Generate a JUnit test case to test the service"` checkbox.

Wizard generates client application and the skeleton for unit test classes.

But what if I add new method to my Web Service or change the definition of existing one? But the test cases can be already modified by someone and there can be a lot of hand-made logic.

Is there a way to do some kind of "update" for client application and unit tests skeletons to fit with changes in Web Service application without rewriting the existing one?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. The issue actually is not exactly an issue.

My concern was that Web Service generation wizard will rewite my changes to generated unit tests. But after few checks I see that wizard rewrites the stub classes and proxy classes for Web Service. This is exactly what I need.

Thanks everyone

Comment: You could accept this answer, so everyone can see problem is solved ;)